# Pairing user on Google Home and an AndroidTV

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, android-tv, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a Google On Actions (AoG) app that I want to allow user to control my AndroidTV via Google Home.

After handling Account Linking with AoG and using DialogFlow fulfillment, I got userId/email to identify an user.

On AndroidTV, I have device id (generated by Android SDK). But I could not pair/match them together (email, device id). I could request user input same email to match with email on Google Home. But it quite complicated for customer.

So I dont want user must input there email on Android TV again. Could someone suggest another way to **pair from User Id I receive on DialogFlow with android Device ID**?

Answer (score 0):

There is no association between a Google Home and Android TV that is exposed to developers. If you want to create this, the best approach would be performing account linking using the user's Google account on both the Home and the Android TV. If you can use Google sign-in, the TV sign-in experience is fairly seamless (or using [Smart Lock](https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android?hl=en)).

Then you would be able to use server push notifications that your Action generates which can be received by a receiving app on your TV to perform some sorts of logic.